# How can i find unique combinations of 2 columns, delete not unique combinations, keeping only first rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that contains 2 columns. And there are data combinations. I want to find if there are not unique combinations and delete them keeping only the first row.

So here is a dataset

```
dim_set = [ ('Customer group$Large', 'DEPARTMENT$Sales'),
        ('Customer group$Medium', 'DEPARTMENT$Sales'),
        ('Customer group$Small', 'DEPARTMENT$Sales'),
        ('DEPARTMENT$Sales', 'Customer group$Large'),
        ('DEPARTMENT$Sales', 'Customer group$Medium'),
        ('DEPARTMENT$Sales', 'Customer group$Small')
        ]
df = pd.DataFrame(dim_set, columns=['dim', 'linked_dim'])
df
```

[image]

the expected output should be

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need sorting each row and remove duplicates:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['dim', 'linked_dim']], axis=1),
                   columns=['dim', 'linked_dim'])
        .drop_duplicates())
print (df)
                     dim        linked_dim
0   Customer group$Large  DEPARTMENT$Sales
1  Customer group$Medium  DEPARTMENT$Sales
2   Customer group$Small  DEPARTMENT$Sales
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work for you

```
import numpy as np
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['dim', 'linked_dim']]),columns=['dim','linked_dim']).drop_duplicates())
print (df)
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess this this more or less the same as in the prev answer.

Comment: Right, However, axis parameter is optional. Thus makes the code simple.